# Jetpack Compose: How to click on Maker in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I use [official](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose) Google Maps Compose lib and I can't understand...how implement click on the marker?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MapContent(city: City)  {
    val pos = LatLng(city.latitude, city.longitude)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(pos, 12f)
    }
    val mapState = rememberMarkerState(position = pos)
    
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        uiSettings = MapUiSettings(zoomControlsEnabled = false)
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = mapState,
            onClick = {
                Timber.tag("GoogleMapClick").d("click!!!")
                false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. Can you help me, what's wrong? I want to click on the marker and show BottomSheet with City info, but it looks like onClick doesn't work...

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.5.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
```

Comment: it's just no messages in Log

Comment: Not a direct answer but in case it's helpful you can see similar example in following (though using `MarkerInfoWindowContent`)  https://github.com/joreilly/GalwayBus/blob/main/android-app/src/main/java/dev/johnoreilly/galwaybus/ui/screens/BusInfoScreen.kt

Comment: I don't know it just doesn't work. I can't understand why

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onInfoWindowClick` instead `onClick`

Here my code that works ;)

```
            Card(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(250.dp)
                .padding()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))) {
                GoogleMap(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(250.dp)
                        .padding(),
                    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
                ) {
                    viewData.items.forEach {
                        val position = LatLng(
                            it.geolocalisation.first(),
                            it.geolocalisation.last())
                        Marker(
                            state = MarkerState(position = position),
                            title = it.nom,
                            snippet = it.categorie,
                            onInfoWindowClick = { _ ->
                                onClickItem(it)
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    if (sheetState.isVisible) sheetState.hide()
                                    else sheetState.show()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I found what's wrong. Google Map onClick events doesn't work on the emulators. But on the real device everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
MarkerInfoWindow(
        state = MarkerState(position = singapore),
    ) {
        if (it.isInfoWindowShown) {
            //do something
            it.hideInfoWindow()
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).